# How to write an algorithm for a turtle to destroy patches in a specific pattern

Tags: algorithm, netlogo

I need a loop or "algorithm" that will make the turtle turn all of the green patches in this pattern to black patches. Aka "eating them".

[the pattern that the turtle must follow and eat all of the patches in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GsGF.png)

I tried using a while loop with the following code but I get an error when the turtle eats all of the patches because of the "face" command. Please help me figure out how to make a loop for this.

```
while [[pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = green]
[
repeat 30
[
  face min-one-of patches with [pcolor = green] [distance myself]
  forward 1
  set pcolor black
```

]
]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: obviously you cannot face a patch that doesn't exist. What is the required behaviour after all the patches have been eaten?

Comment: what is the purpose of `repeat 30` in your code? That makes it so that you continue trying to execute the code even when the patch ahead of the turtle is not green.